# Minor street names are not appearing on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

There only major streets are showing on the map where I used to have the names of the smaller streets.  Other users have reported this and its not answered correctly.

Comment: Do you have an example location?

Comment: Have you tried simply zooming in?

Answer (score 2):

Google explained this change in their blog post of July 25, 2016: [Discover the action around you with the updated Google Maps](https://maps.googleblog.com/2016/07/discover-action-around-you-with-updated.html). Their goal was to have a cleaner look with less text and more emphasis on areas of interest and actionable items. The first screenshot of the post shows that fewer streets are now named on the map:

[image: comparison of Google maps]

Answer (score 1):

Only Google can explain, but an interesting comparison of maps from 2010 to 2016 shows fewer labels but more connecting roads, implying a need to present maps better on mobile devices:

http://www.justinobeirne.com/essay/what-happened-to-google-maps